# what should I say when doing a presentation and I need to leave the next topic to the next team member in my team

Tags: word-usage

I am having a presentation soon. One thing that bothers me is that, we have multiple members in the team and each of us is doing the presentation for a small part of the slides.

So there are points where we have to stop and let the next person to do their part. The problem is, I don't know what exactly should I say at that point. I image can just say "That's it for me then" and the next person will just come up to replace me but I think that's not the best way possible. Can you guys help me?

Also, more specifically if the next person's topic is about `Data Access`, what can I say to make the transition include the topic he or she is gonna present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can say it, but the most common are similar to

- **And now I'd like to introduce Dr Susan Smith, whose paper is called "Data Access"** (suitable for academic or conference situations)
- **Here's where I hand over to Susan Smith, who will explain the implications for Data Access** (suitable for presentation to clients)
- **Now here's Susan with her views on data Data Access** (presentation at work)
- (Addressing Susan) **Susan, can I ask you to take over and tell us about Data Access?** (informal and conversational style, often seen at workshops)

In passing, many consider "gonna" to be extremely informal speech, and you might want to avoid it unless you're certain this register is suitable for your audience and situation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, very informative. Can I ask what did you mean by `register` as in "unless you're certain this register is suitable for your audience and situation."?

Comment: "register" is the word most commonly used to describe the differences in language according to social situation, both in written and spoken forms.  For non-native learners, it is often one of the most difficult things to get right.  As illustration, each of these are ordinary only in specific circumstances: woof-woof, doggie, dog, _canis familiaris_.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)